# Regex: How to force optional groups to match

Tags: regex, robotframework

I have a regex like so

```
set the var (.*) to (.*)(( and )(.*))?
```

and I'm trying to match with with the following sample text

```
set the var VAR to DATA POINT and SEQUENCE
set the var VAR to DATA POINT
set the var VAR to DATA
set the var VAR EXTRA to DATA
```

https://regex101.com/r/6hbrdw/1 as you can see, the first group matches correctly, but the second one matches too much on the cases where the optional **and .*** happens. Is there some way to force those last few groups to match if possible instead of skipping over them?

Also this is regex for Robot Framework so there is no support for extensions **(?...)** like lookarounds

**EDIT:**

Many of you have pointed out that I can use the expression

```
set the var (.*?) to (.*?)(( and )(.*))?$
```

to get the match correctly, this works in the online tester, however this regex seems to fail in Robot Framework where it is being used as the following

```
set the var ${var1:(.*?)} to ${var2:(.*?)}${var3:(( and )(.*))?$}
```

It seems to work in the case of all 3 veriables and the 'and' being present, but when there are just 2 the 2nd group will not match anything

Comment: @IMSoP yes, I've tried using those but the problem I run into is it's not greedy enough. it either selects nothing, or 1 character on that second group, and I can't tell it to end on whitespace|end of line as that group can contain spaces as well

Comment: `set the var (.*?) to (.*?)(( and )(.*))?$` should work. See demo:  https://regex101.com/r/6hbrdw/2

Comment: @J.Doe I don't understand. As anubhava's link shows, it succeeds with all your examples. If you've got an additional example it fails with, please [edit] the question with both that example and the _best_ attempt you have at the regex.

Comment: Please show how you're actually doing this.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've added some context

Comment: You still have shown actual code. What keyword are you using this with? Or are you using it as a decorator to a function?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called a "non-greedy quantifier", and is considered a standard part of most regex engines.

The Python `re` module [documents it here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-6):

> *?, +?, ??
>
> The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE `<.*>` is matched against `'<a> b <c>'`, it will match the entire string, and not just `'<a>'`. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. Using the RE `<.*?>` will match only `'<a>'`.

So I believe the rule you are looking for is:

```
set the var (.*?) to (.*?)(( and )(.*))?
```